# How to copy the data loaded into target table from source table to the text file?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have to load the target table copy of data into the text file at the time of workflow running.(i.e)Whatever data are going into the the target table that should come into the text file also.

Answer (score 2):

You can have two targets. One can be your relational target and the other can be a flat-file target.